# Auto labeling in tasks environment

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, tasks

I have done this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathptmx, amssymb}

\usepackage{tasks}[newest]
\settasks{label = \textbf{\Alph*.}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label = \textbf{Question \arabic*.},
    ref = \arabic*
}
\newcommand\correct{\label{\theenumi}}

%=========================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item How many letters in the word ``Tea'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \correct
        \task $2$
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
    The answer is \ref{1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I intend to automatically label (for example, `\label{1}` for question 1) and manually refer.

I need "The answer is B" (without bold and dot) in the last line, but remain `\ref{1}` for later use (as {1} refers to question 1).

It will be helpful if the solution stays on `tasks` and `enumerate` environments, because I've already used them for my entire document.

Comment: The aux file has `\newlabel{{1}}{{\textbf  {B.}}{1}}` which means you need `\ref{{1}}`

Comment: Also, you might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498299/

Comment: @cgnieder Thank for your quick reply, such a simple solution makes it work perfectly. I took a look at the website you've given, it's great and I'll definitely try it later. But currently, is there any direct way to remove bold and dot of `\ref{{1}}` in my case?

Comment: Yes, separate label and formatting. For example you can define `\newcommand*\tasklabelformat[1]{\textbf{#1.}}` and then set `\settasks{ label = \Alph* , label-format = \tasklabelformat }`.
BTW: you should also adjust the `label-width`, check the warnings in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aux` file to you MWE has the following line:

```
\newlabel{{1}}{{\textbf {B.}}{1}}
```

This means that you need to use `\ref{{1}}` with your approach. However, the reference will then be `\textbf {B.}` , *i.e.*. a bold B with a bold dot.

But if you separate formatting and label you get what you want. You could do

```
\newcommand*\tasklabelformat[1]{\textbf{#1.}}
```

and then set

```
\settasks{
  label = \Alph* ,
  label-format = \tasklabelformat
}
```

[image]

A complete example which also sets the `label-width` according to warings in he log:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathptmx, amssymb}

\newcommand*\tasklabelformat[1]{\textbf{#1.}}

\usepackage{tasks}[newest]
\settasks{
  label = \Alph* ,
  label-format = \tasklabelformat ,
  label-width  = 12pt
}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{
  label = \textbf{Question \arabic*.},
  ref = \arabic*
}
\newcommand\correct{\label{\theenumi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} 
  \item How many letters are in the word ``Tea''?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
      \task $1$
      \task $3$ \correct
      \task $2$
      \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

The answer is \ref{{1}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant. The solution is simple and has everything that I need. Many thanks to @cgnieder.

Comment: hi @cgnieder, I've taken a look at your solution in (tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498299), and I'm interested in how to randomize the questions in your case ?

Comment: @Xuân that link leads nowhere

Comment: Sorry that I don't know how to share link. That's the one you shared before and asked me if I was interested in.
Here the full link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498299/multiple-choice-questions-with-correct-choice-environment